# How to find most recent date compare to current date?

Tags: java, selenium

I created a list for dates in certain format. In that list I'm adding elements from some HTML code. Also I get curent time in format same as in list.

```
List<WebElement> times = driver.findElements(By.tagName("time"));
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

System.out.println(timeStamp);
for (WebElement element: times) {
        System.out.println(element.getText());
    }
```

Now, how to get most recent passed date and compare with current date, because I must count how mach days have been passed?

Comment: Iterate over a list to add its element to itself ?

Comment: As stated above, you already have a list of time webelements.  What are you trying to accomplish in your "for?"

Comment: @BillHileman Sorry, fixed. I just print dates too see does it itterate them correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can do as follows :

- iterate over your elements
- `parse` them to `LocalDate` (set the good pattern in the `formatter`)
- keep only the ones in the past
- get the `max`
- print it

---

```
List<WebElement> times = driver.findElements(By.tagName("time"));

LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

LocalDate mostRecent = times.stream()
            .map(webE -> LocalDate.parse(webE.getText(), formatter))
            .filter(date -> date.isBefore(now))
            .max(Comparator.comparingLong(LocalDate::toEpochDay))
            .orElseThrow(IllegalAccessException::new);

System.out.println(mostRecent);
```

---

```
LocalDate dateBefore;
LocalDate dateAfter;
long daysBetween = DAYS.between(dateBefore, dateAfter);
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'November 19, 2017' could not be parsed at index 3

Comment: @NeoCortex what DateTimeFormatter did you set ?

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);`

Comment: @NeoCortex your need 4 `M`, only 3 is for "Nov", also change line `.map(...)` i've edit it

Comment: I have just one more problem... How to count days betweeen theese two dates?
I'm trying something like this: `System.out.println("Days= "+daysBetween(now, mostRecent));` but doesn't work....

Answer (score 1):

Try using TreeSet.floor() / TreeSet.ceiling().

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/treeset_floor.htm

Comment: Actually, you don't even have to do that unless you have future dates in your set.  Just throw it into a treeset with a reverse ordered comparator, and take the first value.